# Proof of some statement

Tags: calculus, inequality

How can I prove this inequality 
$$|\log(1+x^2)-\log(1+y^2)| \leq |x-y|$$  where  $x, y \in (0,+\infty)$.
I'm trying but not getting any idea how to show.

Please someone help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Use the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) with $f(t)=\log(1+t^2)$ in the interval $[x,y]$ and note that $0\leq f'(t)=2t/(1+t^2)\leq 1$ for $t\geq 0$.

Comment: that's why we have to take modulus in the MVT

Comment: Yes, after MVT take the modulus.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $y>x>0$ we have
$$ \log(1+y^2)-\log(1+x^2) = \int_{x}^{y}\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\,dz \tag{1} $$
and on $\mathbb{R}^+$ we have $\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\leq 1$, since $(1+z^2)-2z = (1-z)^2\geq 0$.
It follows that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+$ the inequality $\left|\log(1+x^2)-\log(1+y^2)\right|\leq \left|x-y\right|$ holds.